# How I can deal with Tuple in Spark Streaming?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have a problem with Spark Scala which I want to multiply Tuple elements in Spark streaming,I get data from kafka to dstream ,my RDD data is like this,

```
(2,[2,3,4,6,5])
(4,[2,3,4,6,5])
(7,[2,3,4,6,5])
(9,[2,3,4,6,5])
```

I want to do this operate using multiplication like this，

```
 (2,[2*2,3*2,4*2,6*2,5*2])
 (4,[2*4,3*4,4*4,6*4,5*4])
 (7,[2*7,3*7,4*7,6*7,5*7])
 (9,[2*9,3*9,4*9,6*9,5*9])
```

Then,I get the rdd like this,

```
 (2,[4,6,8,12,10])
 (4,[8,12,16,24,20])
 (7,[14,21,28,42,35])
 (9,[18,27,36,54,45])
```

Finally,I get Tuple the second element by smallest like this,

```
 (2,4)
 (4,8)
 (7,14)
 (9,18)
```

How can I do this with scala from dstream? I use spark version 1.6

Comment: `rdd.map({ case (i, list) => (i, list.map(x => x*i)) }).map({ case (i, list) => (i, list.min) })`

Comment: Or you can select the min first and then multiply in same `map`, that will be more efficient. `rdd.map({ case (i, list) => (i, i * list.min) })`

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh good answer! Just in case that `i` can be negative, taking  the `min` before multiplication would actually give the maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give you  a demo  with scala

```
// val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("ttt").setMaster("local")
//val  sc = new SparkContext(conf)
// val data =Array("2,2,3,4,6,5","4,2,3,4,6,5","7,2,3,4,6,5","9,2,3,4,6,5")
//val  lines  = sc.parallelize(data)
//change to your data  (each RDD in streaming)
    lines.map(x => (x.split(",")(0).toInt,List(x.split(",")(1).toInt,x.split(",")(2).toInt,x.split(",")(3).toInt,x.split(",")(4).toInt,x.split(",")(5).toInt) ))
      .map(x =>(x._1 ,x._2.min)).map(x => (x._1,x._2* x._1)).foreach(x => println(x))
```

here is the result

```
(2,4)
(4,8)
(7,14)
(9,18)
```

Each RDD in DStream contains data at a specific time interval, and you can manipulate each RDD as you want

Comment: @lee glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say, you are getting tuple rdd in variable **input**:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer    

val result = input
.map(x => {                           // for each element
   var l = new ListBuffer[Int]()      // create a new list for storing the multiplication result
   for(i <- x._1){                    // for each element in the array
      l += x._0 * i                   // append the multiplied result to the new list
   }
   (x._0, l.toList)                  // return the new tuple
})
.map(x => {
   (x._0, x._1.min)                  // return the new tuple with the minimum element in it from the list
})
```

`result.foreach(println)` should result in:

```
(2,4)
(4,8)
(7,14)
(9,18)
```